# Django many-to-one create parent ("one") entry if not already exist

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a comparable setup as the documentation of django describes for a many to one scenario.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']
```

I have situations where the `Reporter` does not yet exist, but `Article` can be created for a non-existing `reporter`, so I want the `Article` model to make a `Reporter` if it doesn't exist yet. I guess what I need is a check if the `Reporter` already exists and if not create a new one. Is this the best way? Or does Django have a better, build in, method for this? Al reporters will have specific ID that is

I very new to Django and have trouble finding resources about this, probably because I'm missing terminology, so I some can point me in the right direction I would already be helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) or [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) function.

```
reporter, created_reporter = Reporter.objects.get_or_create(
    email=reporter_email,
    first_name=reporter_first_name,
    last_name=reporter_last_name,
)
reporter.articles.create(...)
```

Additionally, if you make `Reporter.email` unique you can do the following which is more robust as it takes advantage of your databases uniqueness constraint.

```
reporter, created_reporter = Reporter.objects.get_or_create(
    email=report_email,
    defaults={
        "first_name": reporter_first_name,
        "last_name": reporter_last_name,
    }
)
```

Doing that will check if the reporter exists based on the email and if it doesn't, then it'll create one using the default values.